# How to put background-image in a section in html

Tags: html

How to put background-image in a section in html
How to put background-image in a section in html
How to put background-image in a section in html
How to put background-image in a section in html
How to put background-image in a section in html

Comment: dude just use an online documentation or cheatsheet for this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't spam your question, it just confuses people.
You can do it like this:

CSS:

```
.example {
background: url("imageurl") no-repeat center;
height: 100vh;
background-size: cover;
```

}